# Visual Studio reloads nugets endlessly

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, nuget, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2022

Visual Studio (2022/2019) reloads endlessly the Nugets in NuGet manager, there is not possible to upgrade or to check them to do some action.
[image]

The list appears and then immediately gets reloaded.

Does have anyone workaround that problem?

I tried to feedback to Microsoft the VS Studio bug via VS feedback, however, they seem to have problems not only on Desktop Sowftare...
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try to check if you can open this link(https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json) in your browser. If it cannot be opened, it may be a network problem.

You can try linking vpn it might be useful.

Please let me know if it doesn't work and I'll create an issue for you on DC.

Comment: there is any problem to open and read the mentionned json file

Comment: I mean, the list is fully loaded (so, it seems, is reads well). Then reloaded.

Comment: I reported this issue on DC, you can follow [this link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Visual-Studio-nuget-package-manager-relo/10213078?port=1025&fsid=38c22c5e-1a26-4d64-a87f-0c8470385a73).